# app store wont let me download free apps

Tags: applications

when I try to download a free app it asks for my credit card info, and I don't have one and I say none but it just restarts and wont let me pick none.

Comment: it wont let me update either

Answer (score 0):

Do you participate in a family share?
maybe the admin credit card is out of date?

I had the same problem because his credit card was not valid anymore.

if not maybe apple just trying to make people put a credit card on individual accounts.